# django oscar - Dashboard/voucher

Tags: dashboard, django-oscar

I'm not able to add voucher from the dashboard. The Datetimepicker field doesn't pick the date.
In django-oscar==1.5.1, Django==1.10.8

Thank you

Comment: You're going to have to ask a more specific question and tell us what you tried.

Comment: I had similar issue with the fancy datetime pickers in the dashboard JS & HTML. I ended up removing the fancy classes & using vanilla HTML5 datetime inputs. Also, if that doesn't help, try expanding on your question by adding more details &/or screenshots.

Comment: I'm using django oscar for my project, added bootstrap 4 templates, after adding  datetimepicker is not working in dashboard/voucher, were as datetimepicker is working in dashboard/offers, there are no errors it's not accepting the date and time, so I can't add the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

replace `<script src="{% static "oscar/js/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js" %}"></script>` 
with `<script src="{% static "oscar/js/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js" %}"></script>` in your dashboard/layout.html file. Make sure you have the minified version of the above file in you project's local path.

Django oscar has a feature branch [feature/datetime-for-vouchers](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/feature/datetime-for-vouchers/src/oscar/templates/oscar/dashboard/layout.html), refer this for crosschecking and more info.

Answer (score 0):

It worked, Thank you very much it helped me a lot.
Thanks for spending your valuable time, most of them don't answer the question only the few who are passionate about this field